# Serialize objects to a map with the object class as the key?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm writing a application using Spring boot and jackson for JSON parsing. I need to handle another service which produces JSON like this:

```
{
  "task-id": 5081,
  "task-created-on": {
    "java.util.Date": 1631022026000
  }
}
```

Notably, certain fields like the date field here are serialized into a map with a single key-value pair, where the key is a java classname and the value is the actual value of the field.

I've been going through the jackson documentation and haven't found anything about this format. Is there a way to configure jackson to produce and parse fields in this format?

At a minimum, I need to handle dates formatted this way. But I believe the service also uses this format for other objects, where the map key will be the name of some arbitrary java class and the value will be a map of its own. So I'd be interested in a solution that handles more than just dates if possible.

Comment: Question to avoid misunderstanding : `task-created-on` is a `Date` field in your pojo, so it would normally serialized as `"task-created-on": 1631022026000` ?

Comment: @dariosicily Yes, that's correct. "task-created-on" should be a Date field if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to solve the issue with the use of a custom [`JsonSerializer`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonSerializer.html) and applying the [`JsonSerialize`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/annotation/JsonSerialize.html) over the fields in the pojo you are interested like below :

```
public class Task {

    @JsonProperty("task-id")
    private int taskId;

    @JsonProperty("task-created-on")
    @JsonSerialize(using = ObjectSerializer.class)
    Date taskCreatedOn; 
}
```

The custom serializer will use the [`JsonGenerator.html#writeObjectField`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonGenerator.html#writeObjectField(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)) to serialize a generic object (`Date` or other java class) as propertyname : {"classname" : value} :

```
public class ObjectSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Object> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(Object t, JsonGenerator jg, SerializerProvider sp) throws IOException {
        jg.writeStartObject();
        jg.writeObjectField(t.getClass().getName(), t);
        jg.writeEndObject();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

It can be easily done with **custom serializer** in Jackson by following steps.
First, create objects for serialization as follows:

```java
class MyDateObject {
    private Date date;

    //general getter/setter
}

class Task {
    @JsonProperty("task-id")
    private int taskId;

    @JsonProperty("task-created-on")
    private MyDateObject taskCreatedOn;

    //general getters/setters
}
```

Second, define your custom serializer: (Please note that I used `myDateObject.getDate().getClass().getName()` to get the class name of date field.)

```java
class DateSerializer extends StdSerializer<MyDateObject> {
    public DateSerializer() {
        this(null);
    }

    protected DateSerializer(Class<MyDateObject> t) {
        super(t);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(MyDateObject myDateObject, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
        jsonGenerator.writeStartObject();
        jsonGenerator.writeNumberField(myDateObject.getDate().getClass().getName(), myDateObject.getDate().getTime());
        jsonGenerator.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

Finally, register the serializer with `ObjectMapper` for the `MyDateObject` class and perform the serialization:

```java
MyDateObject myDateObject = new MyDateObject();
myDateObject.setDate(new Date());

Task task = new Task();
task.setTaskId(5081);
task.setTaskCreatedOn(myDateObject);

SimpleModule simpleModule = new SimpleModule();
simpleModule.addSerializer(MyDateObject.class, new DateSerializer());

ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.registerModule(simpleModule);

System.out.println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(task));
```

The expected output is:

> {"task-id":5081,"task-created-on":{"java.util.Date":1633402076254}}

---

Please refer to [Jackson – Custom Serializer](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-custom-serialization) for more information.

Comment: Thanks, @LHCHIN. I went with the other answer because it's more general.

Comment: It's OK! I didn't notice that you wanna a general solution, so I just provide a straightforward one to your original question. : )